# JSON.parse Unexpected end of JSON input but the code process correctly the data

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a Cloudflare worker to return a JSON. The code running on the worker is pretty simple

```
//return JSON
    const data = {
      pswd: psk_db,
    };

    json = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  }

  return new Response(json, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
    })
```

Now, for some reason, I correctly recieve the response but when I call the javascript

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(Http.response);
        document.getElementById("json_response_code").textContent = parsed.pswd;
```

I got

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at RequestCode.Http.onreadystatechange (index.html:83:27)
```

But I still correctly get the value on `parsed.pswd`

I can't find the issue as the code works but it throws error anyway

EDIT

`Console.log(Http.response)` shows

```
{
  "pswd": "nicola"
}
```

Yes, I'm using it; added code

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const url = my_url;

      Http.open("GET", url);
      Http.send();

      Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        console.log(Http.response);
        var parsed = JSON.parse(Http.response);
        document.getElementById("json_response_code").textContent = parsed.pswd;
  };
```

Comment: What does `console.log(Http.response)` show?

Comment: are you using XMLHttpRequest? `onreadystatechange` suggests you are, and using it wrong - show the code making the request - or use `onload` instead of the ancient `onreadystatechange` - note, if using onreadystatechange, the full response is only available once `.readystate` is `XMLHttpRequest.DONE`

Comment: @FelixKling added more info

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, i'm using it

Comment: yes, you're using it wrong as I thought

Comment: @JaromandaX what do you mean? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [read documented examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readystatechange_event#examples) for how to use it - note the conditional `if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {` - I recommend you use `onload` instead - change `Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {` to `Http.onload = (e) => {` and you're done - but, read the docs to understand where you went wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX you were right. You can post it as an answer as it fixed the issue

Comment: At this point it might be easier to ditch XMLHTTPR altogether and use `fetch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Jaromanda-X `Http.onreadystatechange = (e)` was used in the wrong way.

Solution has been

```
  Http.onload = (e) => {
    // In local files, status is 0 upon success in Mozilla Firefox
    if (Http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      const status = Http.status;
      if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
        // The request has been completed successfully
        console.log(Http.responseText);
        var parsed = JSON.parse(Http.response);
        document.getElementById("json_response_code").textContent =
          parsed.pswd;
      } else {
        // Oh no! There has been an error with the request!
        console.log(Error);
      }
    }
  };
  Http.send();
```